# Add static rows in dynamic mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I use mat-table and would like to insert two static lines. In these static lines input is made and later stored in the back-end. Can you please tell me how to insert the static rows and make them available for processing?

My Code:

```
// HTML
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <div *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; let i = index">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.attribute">
      <!-- Table-Header -->
      <th mat-header-cell class="table-header-bg-second" id="table-header-font-second" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>
          {{ column.name }}
        </div>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell class="table-content-bg-second" id="table-content-font-second" *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled-ranges': column.disabledRanges, 'disabled-assignment': column.disabledAssignment}">
        <div formArrayName="rows" *ngIf="attributesWithFormControls.includes(column.attribute); else otherColumns">
          <span class="edit-cell" [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-form-field>
              <label>
                <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="column.attribute" />
              </label>
            </mat-form-field>
          </span>
        </div>
        <ng-template #otherColumns>
          {{ column.object !== null ? row[column.object][column.attribute] : row[column.attribute] }}
        </ng-template>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </div>

  <!-- Display columns -->
  <tr mat-header-row class="optimize-header-row" *matHeaderRowDef="columns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row class="optimize-row" *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>
</table>
```

```
// TS
private monthColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    {attribute: '1', name: 'Jan', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false},
    {attribute: '2', name: 'Feb', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false},
    {attribute: '3', name: 'Mrz', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false},
    {attribute: '4', name: 'Apr', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false},
  ];

  private afterMonthsColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    {attribute: 'sum', name: 'Summe', object: 'values', disabledRanges: true, disabledAssignment: false},
    {attribute: 'note', name: 'Anmerkung', object: null, disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false},
  ];

  // Merged arrays
  public displayedColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    ...this.monthColumns,
    ...this.afterMonthsColumns
  ];
```

Comment: Can you add the complete html for the `mat-table`?

Comment: HTML I have extended

Comment: I suppose you can use the footer of the table to put your inputs inside: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#footer-row

Comment: Have you found a way to solve that? Would be very helpful

Comment: Alice Arkalykova Yes, I have found a solution. I wrote an addRow() with the help of FormArray in which you can specify in the for loop how many rows should be displayed and you can call the function in ngOnInit. What should be in the respective columns can be added via the template. My example is not with mat-table, but can also be implemented in mat-table. My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-ngkst3?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts